# Outputting file with line numbers as html

Tags: python, html

I've noticed that you can use python libdiff to output a side by side comparison of files with their differences.  Is there an easy way to output just one file in python as html with line numbers?

Comment: What kind of file are you dealing with?

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert a file to HTML and then output the contents with line numbers?

Comment: Just a text file, say text.py. Also I don't want to convert the file just output and HTML version with line numbers.

Comment: `text.py` sounds more like Python source code than plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`HtmlFormatter`](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/) of [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) supports a `linenos` option to enable line numbers.  Pygments also features syntax highlighting for many languages, if desired, and it takes care of escaping HTML meta-characters.  (For the line numbers only Pygments might be overkill.)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the file, but there's one for a text file:

```
f = open(filename)
for num, line in enumerate(f):
    print "<span style=\'display: inline-block;width: 50px;\'>" + str(num+1) + "</span>" + line + "<br/>"
```

Comment: You really should use `open` and not `file`